# git extension does not show in the side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't see the git extension icon in side bar.

[image: capture VSCODE]

Comment: Did you hide it? Right click on the bar and see if "Source control" is unchecked (or ctrl+shift+g). other possibility: git not installed or detected...

Comment: Just for your future info - that area where the icons are is called the `Activity Bar`.  When you click on one, it opens it information into the `Activity Bar`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:
Press F1 and type "Source Control", then select any option. This should show your extension again.

Answer (score 1):

It won't appear as its own icon, it will use the source control icon. See my annotation below.

Your icon may differ but should be similar.

[image]